# If $\alpha,\beta$ are two real numbers s.t. $\alpha \sqrt{P(A|B)}+\beta\sqrt{P(\bar{A}|B)}=2/3$, what's the value of $\frac{27}{8}(\alpha^2+\beta^2)$?

Tags: probability

Let $A$ and $B$ be two independent events. If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are any two real numbers such that $$\alpha \sqrt{P(A|B)}+ \beta\sqrt{P(\bar{A}|B)}=2/3,$$ then the value of $\frac{27}{8}(\alpha^2+\beta^2)$ lies between.

**MY ATTEMPT:**
By using AM - GM mean we can figure out the lower boundary of the value is $4$  but I am facing difficulty in finding the upper boundary. I have tried to expand the equation which simplifies to
$$\alpha\sqrt{P(A)}+ \beta\sqrt{P(\bar{A})}=2/3 $$
assuming $P(A) = x$ and $P(\bar{A}) = 1-x$ and simplify and tried to isolate the $x$ and use the fact that $x$ lies on the interval $[0,1]$, but I failed.

Please, help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no upper bound. Take $\alpha=n$ (a positive integer) and solve the given equation for $\beta$. Note that the hypothesis is now satisfied but $\alpha^{2}+\beta^{2} \geq \alpha^{2} \geq n^{2}$. Hence there is no upper bound for $\alpha^{2}+\beta^{2}$